# Go - Traversing nested structs

Tags: go, reflection

I have a complex structure of this sort:

```
type InFoo struct {
    v3 int
}
type Bar struct {
    v1 int
    v2 InFoo
}
type Foo struct {
    A int
    B string
    C Bar
}
```

At runtime, this could be further deeply nested. I wrote a function below to traverse the fields as below:

```
func main() {
    f := Foo{A: 10, B: "Salutations", C: Bar{v1: 10, v2: InFoo{v3: 20}}}
    fType := reflect.TypeOf(f)
    newexaminer(fType)
}

// recursive traversal
func newexaminer(t reflect.Type) {
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        f := t.Field(i)
        fmt.Println(f.Name, f.Type.Kind(), f.Type)
        if f.Type.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
            // recurse if struct
            newexaminer(f.Type)
        }

    }
}
```

Although this works but I am not sure if there is a better/optimized way to do this. Please suggest!

- EDIT:1
  Based on comments I changed approach to:

```
func main() {
    f := Foo{A: 10, B: "Salutations", C: Bar{v1: 10, v2: InFoo{v3: 20}}}
    jsonRes, err := json.Marshal(f)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    var iRes interface{}

    err = json.Unmarshal(jsonRes, &iRes)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    res := iRes.(map[string]interface{})

    for _, v := range res {

        fmt.Println(v)
        // need to type assert v again to extract map keys/values
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/_TXrRGxpIyx

Is this an idomatic way of traversing structs. Looks like this will still need multiple assertions and loops to get to the inner most fields. Is this an ideal approach for a parsing a complex json document or is there a better way to do this

Comment: Can you add more specifics about what you plan to do while traversing your struct tree? If you're only dealing with a handful of types then type assertions / switches might be more performant. Is there a reason you have tags on `A` in `Foo`? They don't seem to be used in your code.

Comment: I am trying to write a kubernetes controller where the spec for controller could contain multiple of these fields. For example, a git repo at the top, branches, credentials etc as nested structures. Not sure if there is a better way to do this but I am assuming there is a  better way to somehow flatten this structure and easily extract fields & their values as well. The above solution so far is just getting the fields. I have removed tags for now since this question does not need those. Hope this helps

Comment: I think you want to traverse the reflected value, not its type. you could also json encode the struct, decode it to a map[string]interface{} and browse that.

Comment: @mh-cbon, updated based on your suggestion. Thank you!